# Power drill requirements for steel-reinforced concrete

Tags: concrete, powertools, steel

We have the need for a new power drill (old 25+ year Bosch finally died) and I'm trying to determine the requirements for our situation. We are in a new build (European concrete) property with the need to drill countless holes for hanging lamps (under 1/2" for sure) etc...

The ceilings are very very tough to drill in (yes that's how the Bosch died) and we have been told by the building constructor that they are 200mm steel-reinforced concrete and we should hire a HILTI! I understand that it is a mesh type system. Using a metal detector seems to confirm this but I'll ask again tomorrow. Also for clarity, i'm trying to drill holes immediately next to the location where the light cable comes in.

As we need a power drill anyway, I would like to get one that covers the ceiling requirement if possible. From what I have been reading, when drilling through such material, it is important to have a drill that can run at a low speed and high torque settings (more important to invest in drill bits).

Right now the requirements I think I need are:

1. Corded (would *like* a cordless but would a 18V. get the job done?)
2. Speed selection (down to 400 rpm)
3. Torque - as many settings as possible
4. SDS (for masonry)
5. Combi style

Also a stupid question...I see in power drill reviews sentences such as "The PSB1800 can drill 30 mm into wood and 10 mm into steel and masonry." Why is this? Surely the depth it can drill in depends on the drill bit?

> this was kindly answered as likely referring to the diameter.

I would appreciate feedback on my requirements. I'm I missing anything? Will a hobby/DIY type of drill be up to the task?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to drill through the 200mm ceiling? Surely those above may not be happy...

Comment: Quite right Mike! I don't wish to drill through it but into it to hang some standard lamps.

Comment: The 30mm and 10mm are almost certainly **diameters** of holes they are advertising the drill can manage.

Comment: I think the standard answer is, "get a Bosch bulldog", but I'm a little more concerned about your structure. Can you be assured that you don't have a post-tensioned slab above you? These are slabs with steel cables running through them that, well, tension the slab. Even nicking one of these cables can be disastrous.

Comment: If you hit steel reinforcement , find a new place to drill. A steel bit will not drill concrete and a masonry bit does a very poor job cutting steel.

Comment: Ecnerwal : Many thanks. that now makes sense  
  
AloysiusDefenestrate, blacksmith37 : the building constructor told us it ran along across the whole ceiling. I assume a kind of mesh but will double confirm tomorrow. I have a metal detector that also detects metal everywhere along the ceiling. And just for clarity, i'm trying to drill holes immediately next to the electrical light cable. 

I would be thankful for any thoughts on the spec for such a drill